# Selenium unable to locate element on website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromium

so I'm trying to build a program for my jobs website to send me notifications when new shifts are available (PlanDay to be specific). I'm using selenium, and I've been able to login and go to the specific site for joboffers. Before this site I've been able to locate elements just fine, but it seems like selenium can't locate any elements on this site. I've tried with xPath, class, id and I've given it long pauses to make sure it loads beforehand. Currently the part trying to locate the element looks like this:

```
waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
el = waiter.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_M_CM_CM_mod_OpenForBookingControl_RdgTimesheet_ctl00__0"]')))

print(el)
```

This is the element

`<tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_M_CM_CM_mod_OpenForBookingControl_RdgTimesheet_ctl00__0" style="cursor:pointer !important;;">`

And I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bjar3563\Desktop\Planday Notification\test.py", line 51, in <module>
    el = waiter.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_M_CM_CM_mod_OpenForBookingControl_RdgTimesheet_ctl00__0"]')))
  File "C:\Users\bjar3563\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\bjar3563\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\bjar3563\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_M_CM_CM_mod_OpenForBookingControl_RdgTimesheet_ctl00__0"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.138)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B6DCE3+50899]
        (No symbol) [0x00AFE111]
        (No symbol) [0x00A05588]
        (No symbol) [0x00A308F9]
        (No symbol) [0x00A30AFB]
        (No symbol) [0x00A5F902]
        (No symbol) [0x00A4B944]
        (No symbol) [0x00A5E01C]
        (No symbol) [0x00A4B6F6]
        (No symbol) [0x00A27708]
        (No symbol) [0x00A2886D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DD3EAE+2566302]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E092B1+2784417]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E0327C+2759788]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C05740+672048]
        (No symbol) [0x00B08872]
        (No symbol) [0x00B041C8]
        (No symbol) [0x00B042AB]
        (No symbol) [0x00AF71B7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75EBFEF9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77887BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77887B8E+238]
```

I am not sure what the problem is, but in the very top (I'm not well versed in html, so not sure if it makes a difference) it says ".

Hope there is enough information for it to make some sense, and thanks for any help in advance:))

Comment: Why are you expecting a `<tr>` element to be clickable?  Clickable elements are usually things like buttons and links.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm not really excpecting it to, and it is not the problem at hand (I just pasted the last thing i tried). The problem is that the element is not able to be located at all, even when i get the script to wait a minute (and I've tried ID, Class and xPath)

Comment: The code calls `expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(...)`, therefore the code expects the element to _exist_ and be _clickable_.  If you don't expect the element to be clickable, why are you calling that function?

Comment: @Noob, can you provide the URL if it's public, that would help the community to give you the solution

Comment: @AjeetVerma I don’t think so unfortunately. You have to be logged in to be able to be on the specific site (with shifts and such). The url also contains my location of work which I’m not too keen on sharing. But it is via the website Planday

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this in the future, if the website has an iFrame (ctrl + f and search for iFrame), you have to select it with "switch_to_frame()" or the appropriate command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).